# Extremely high loads despite Caching

Tags: mysql, centos, scalability, high-load

Okay I've got a nice dedicated server running CentOs 6 with 16gb of ram, dual xenon processors, etc. However I've been experiencing high loads due to mysql. Randomly the load will go below 1.0, and page generation time will be < 30ms, and the site is preforming smoothly. This is with about 100 concurrent users, serving less than 200 pages/minute. However 99% of the time its very slow and has crazy high loads usually at least 4 sometimes in the 100s. We did not use to have this problem, this server used to be able to handled 400 concurrent users and 1000 pages/minute without having the loads go above 1.5.

The first thing I did was implement db caching in PHP with [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/). That helped out a little bit but did not resolve the problem.

I've looked all over the internet and cannot seem to find out what is wrong. I asked a friend to take a look and he had no clue. I got my host to switch us over to a new machine, same problem after a few hours. We should not be getting this high a load for the traffic we are getting.

I'm starting to think it might have something to do with /tmp. I was able to get the load down back to normal for a while after running 'tmpwatch --mtime --all 1 /tmp'. However that did not work again after the loads spiked.

If anyone has any idea of what is wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm not sure what you might use as metrics, but I've included some I think might help.

'top' output:

```
top - 22:02:36 up 1 day, 23:39,  1 user,  load average: 4.01, 4.38, 4.50
Tasks: 233 total,   1 running, 231 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 25.5%us,  2.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 70.5%id,  2.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16331836k total, 16034868k used,   296968k free,   375472k buffers
Swap: 18546680k total,        0k used, 18546680k free, 14421512k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                        
31149 mysql     20   0 1589m  32m 6024 S 191.0  0.2   5:54.80 mysqld                                                        
27575 apache    20   0  312m  13m 3464 S  2.7  0.1   0:04.06 httpd                                                          
29427 apache    20   0  317m  18m 3484 S  2.7  0.1   0:02.76 httpd                                                          
25331 apache    20   0  311m  12m 3440 S  2.3  0.1   0:05.55 httpd                                                          
21331 apache    20   0  408m  15m 3676 S  2.0  0.1   0:08.57 httpd                                                          
24226 apache    20   0  314m  14m 3484 S  2.0  0.1   0:06.45 httpd                                                          
32352 apache    20   0  311m  12m 3424 S  2.0  0.1   0:01.01 httpd                                                          
32377 apache    20   0  312m  13m 3484 S  2.0  0.1   0:00.86 httpd                                                          
  774 apache    20   0  312m  12m 3108 S  1.7  0.1   0:00.11 httpd                                                          
28165 apache    20   0  406m  12m 3588 S  1.7  0.1   0:03.76 httpd                                                          
30516 apache    20   0  311m  12m 3476 S  1.7  0.1   0:02.04 httpd                                                          
31019 apache    20   0  313m  13m 3436 S  1.7  0.1   0:01.68 httpd                                                          
31020 apache    20   0  314m  15m 3484 S  1.7  0.1   0:01.71 httpd                                                          
  657 apache    20   0  311m  12m 3108 S  1.3  0.1   0:00.20 httpd                                                          
27731 apache    20   0  406m  12m 3572 S  1.3  0.1   0:03.69 httpd                                                          
28180 apache    20   0  313m  13m 3480 S  1.3  0.1   0:03.43 httpd                                                          
30565 apache    20   0  314m  14m 3488 S  1.3  0.1   0:02.07 httpd
```

'df' output

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root  461164576  45283168 392455568  11% /
tmpfs                  8165916         0   8165916   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               247919     72922    162197  32% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-tmp     1032088    137344    842316  15% /tmp
```

'iostat' output

```
Linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 (domain redacted)   09/05/2012  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           4.88    0.00    0.49    1.53    0.00   93.09

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda              18.03        98.46       787.86   17060770  136515216
dm-0             76.33        98.15       605.19   17006740  104862680
dm-1              0.00         0.02         0.00       3176          0
dm-2             22.78         0.21       182.06      35730   31546312
```

Comment: Are you running an off-the-shelf app (and which one) or custom written software?

Comment: A dump of your MySQL server's variables/status/config file could be useful.

Comment: @MichaelHampton just a normal LAMP stack, however with a custom php CMS

Answer (score 0):

There are two places to start diagnosing this:

1. Check if MySQL needs tuning; [mysqltuner](http://mysqltuner.pl) is a great automated tool to check your configuration (including live stats) against the recommended configuration.
2. See how many files are in `/tmp` when performance is low, and which filesystem it is - and also how "large" the directory is.  If it is super-huge, or has lots of files, you might benefit from putting it on `tmpfs`, which should be a little faster.  (...or avoiding too many files there. :)

The most likely starting point is to find out if your production load is causing any tuning issues with MySQLtuner though.

Comment: Heres the /etc/fstab line for /tmp:                         `/dev/mapper/vg-tmp /tmp                    ext4    discard,noatime 1 2` according to df, use was at about 30%

Comment: I played around with the cache and load setting for mysql. None of them seemed to have any effect :( (and before you ask, yes I restarted mysql before checking to see if changes took effect)